# How to feed dataprovider from multiple files in testng

Tags: java, testng

I have a requirement where in I maintain multiple files in a folder and my dataprovider method will read set of files and constructs final object array to return. My method looks below but it is reading only one file eventhough I am iterating over all the files. Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

```
    public  Object[][] getTestCaseInformationFromFile() throws Exception{
            String testDataFile=mdfUtil.readFileAsString("TestDataFilesConfiguration.xml");
//retrieving directory path
            String directoryPath=mdfUtil.getPostId("testData/directoryPath", testDataFile);
//retrieving file names
            ArrayList al=mdfUtil.getAssociatedIDs("testData/file", testDataFile);
            Object[][] data = null;
            for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
                csvFile=directoryPath+al.get(i);
                System.out.println("csvFile-===="+csvFile);
                log.info("Loading data provider TestCaseInformation...");
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines=readCSVFile(csvFile);
                int testSize = lines.size();
                log.info("Test file has {} tests contained within it." ,testSize);
                data = new Object[testSize][3];
                for ( int k=0;k<lines.size();k++ ) {
                    ArrayList line=lines.get(k);
                    System.out.println("K values is "+k);
                    List testData=new ArrayList();
                    List validationData=new ArrayList();
                    testData=line.subList(line.indexOf("IDS")+1,line.indexOf("IDE"));
                    validationData=line.subList(line.indexOf("VDS")+1,line.indexOf("VDE"));
                    System.out.println("testData is==="+testData);
                    String testCaseName=(String)testData.get(4);
                    data[k][0]=testCaseName;
                    data[k][1]=testData;
                    data[k][2]=validationData;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("data lenght is="+data.length);
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: what is `mdfUtil` and what are doing it's methods... problem seem to be there... you want to have a `File[]` with all files inside `testData/directoryPath`?? because seems you are only reading `TestDataFilesConfiguration.xml` file....

Comment: mdfUtil is just a class which is having some functions to parse xml files..I configured the directory and file names in TestDataFilesConfiguration.xml ,when I parse it will give me all the file names over which I want to iterate and read the data

Comment: are you sure you get the correct data from it?

Comment: yes ..getting proper data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` needs to be moved outside the loop.  when you declare it inside the loop, it won't be accessible outside of it. You will need to figure out how to set the array size prior.  The way you've written it, you are getting results of just the last CSV file, correct?  If you want to use Object, then this is how you would declare it:

```
data = new Object[<some value>][3];

for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
    csvFile = directoryPath + al.get(i);
    System.out.println("csvFile-===="+csvFile);
    log.info("Loading data provider TestCaseInformation...");
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines=readCSVFile(csvFile);
    int testSize = lines.size();
    log.info("Test file has {} tests contained within it." ,testSize);
    for ( int k=0;k<lines.size();k++ ) {
        ArrayList line=lines.get(k);
        System.out.println("K values is "+k);
        List testData=new ArrayList();
        List validationData=new ArrayList();

        testData=line.subList(line.indexOf("IDS")+1,line.indexOf("IDE"));
        validationData=line.subList(line.indexOf("VDS") + 1,line.indexOf("VDE"));
        System.out.println("testData is==="+testData);
        String testCaseName=(String)testData.get(4);
        data[k][0]=testCaseName;
        data[k][1]=testData;
        data[k][2]=validationData;
    }
}
```

If it were me, I would instead, declare `data` as an arraylist, populate the arraylist with your results, then convert to Object, and return the Object.  This is how you would convert your arraylist to object, so you can return it in dataprovider:

```
    // Now that we know the size of the list, we can define the array size
    Object[][] retObj = new Object[list1.size()][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        retObj[i][1] = list1.get(i);
    }

    return retObj;
```

Comment: Yes you are correct Greg...I was thinking how I can set the <Some value> in data = new Object[<some value>][3];...I have one question will Lazy data provider solve my problem?

Comment: i just provided you a way to solve your problem using array list.

Comment: Lazy data provider has perfectly solved my problem and I felt that would be the more elegant approach to deal with memory related exceptions if number of lines in each file grows drastically.Your approch suits best for files with moderate number of lines. Thanx for your time